# From shell script call a python function of python script located at custom location

Tags: python, shell

My python file: `/root/src/foo.py`

```
#/root/src/foo.py

def add(a,b):
    '''add(a,b) --> a+b'''
    return a+b
```

How do I call `foo.add(a,b)` from a shell script? I got this suggestion from somewhere:

```
python -c "import foo; print(foo.x(1, 2))"
```

But it won't work if the shell script and `foo.py` are in a separate locations.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the folder to your pythonpath

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/foo python -c "import foo;print(foo.add(5,6))"
```

should work (in this case it just sets pythonpath, not adds to it)